# Potential Caching issue with Timber on wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

My Wordpress site uses Timber, a plugin that allows me to use Twig templates. I have a page that seems cached, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have a page called 'Bio', which is a standard WP page. I am trying to edit my twig template, and none of my changes are showing.

Here is my page.php template that will render my twig template:

```php
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['post'] = $post;
Timber::render( array( 'page-' . $post->post_name . '.twig'), $context, false );
```

If I `echo` the full template name that I am sending to the render function, the value is `page-bio.twig`, which is correct when I hit the url for my Bio page.

Here is the original `page-bio.twig` file:

```
{% extends "page-templates/contained.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <article class="post-type-{{post.post_type}}" id="post-{{post.ID}}">
        <h1 class="article-h1">{{post.title}}</h1>
        <section class="article-content">
            {{ post.content }}
        </section>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the new `page-bio.twig` template (I'm simply adding an H1 tag at the top of my content block):

```
{% extends "page-templates/contained.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>change?</h1>
    <article class="post-type-{{post.post_type}}" id="post-{{post.ID}}">
        <h1 class="article-h1">{{post.title}}</h1>
        <section class="article-content">
            {{ post.content }}
        </section>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

Locally, I am seeing my changes to `page-bio.twig` show up in the browser. When I test on my server (hosted by goDaddy), I do not see my changes at all.

The only way to see new changes is to either change the name of my twig file, or change the name/slug of my Wordpress page.

I am not having this problem on any other page  on my site. I am reading [Timber's documentation on Caching](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/performance/), and I am not seeing anything helpful.

Does anyone out there know whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered a twig file named `page-bio.twig` had been uploaded to the root of my theme directory by mistake, and this was the file being rendered instead of the real template file which was in my `views` directory.

In other words, Timber was using a twig file of the same name found in a different directory.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should accept your own answer for the benefit of others that may visit this question later.